# Headless mode using selenium is not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

As whatsapp require barcode to scan, I want it to scan for the first time and afterwards it will run in headless mode. Any Suggestion, here's my code?

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()

options.headless=True

options.add_argument("headless")

#options.headless = True

options.add_argument("no-sandbox")

options.add_argument("start-maximized")

options.add_argument("window-size=1900,1080");

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

#options.add_argument(CHROME_PROFILE_PATH)

browser=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe', options=options)

browser.maximize_window()

browser.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a screenshot of the page, then access it, scan it with phone and it should work as if you scanned it in browser. you can use the screenshot function of selenium itself I guess.

Comment: Yes, but i want one time scan, and after that it will run directly with headless mode.

Comment: Then you wont be coming around opening 2 browsers, one in headless mode and one in normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

Remove options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() , you re assigning empty options object to options identifier again.:

Also add remote debugging port to access ui of headless browser ,

Close all chrome before running the script ,

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()

options.headless=True

options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=1559")

options.add_argument(
"user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")

options.add_argument("no-sandbox")

options.add_argument("start-maximized")

options.add_argument("window-size=1900,1080");


browser=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\ChromeDriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe', options=options)

browser.maximize_window()

browser.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')

input("Scan the bar code and press enter")
```

Now open another chrome and navigate to :

```
  http://127.0.0.1:1559
```

Click the inspectable  link:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it throw an error like these  "unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:1559" .please help me out from these.

Comment: @shreyasnaik updated the answer use 
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=1559")

Comment: Its give time out error, but by adding "options=chromeoptions() " its working by opening the browser. But its not working headlessly.

Comment: @shreyasnaik tested the code and it works as it is could you restart your browser and try again ? change port if you are getting time out even after restart